# how to run a Ruby on rails server

Tags: ubuntu, ruby

Would anyone have a tip for how to run a ruby on rails server? There is an API that I would like to explore.

[This is the git repo.](https://github.com/epri-dev/OpenADR-Virtual-Top-Node/releases)

Thanks for any tips, I just dont have any experience for what would be needed to run this... I am Ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver.

Thanks

***EDIT***
I have not tried anything as I do not have any experience with Ruby on rails or Perl. If this was a Python distribution web service I do have experience with that..

Comment: Hello. Are you looking for how to install Ruby on Rails with an Apache or Nginx? There is also [Puma web server, which comes distributed with Rails by default](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). The manual that you linked also has references to how configure Apache with SSL with Ruby at page 80. Could you clarify what did you try and what did not work by editing your question?

Comment: Thanks for the link I maybe able to run with this :)

Comment: One other real dumb question, sorry dont know alot about this stuff.... Could I ever run this Puma web server on a rasp pi? Its only for internal experiments on a LAN in my house.. I have an old B+ laying around but I am not sure if a rasp pi has the processing power or not.